# What is a word describing when someone pronounces a word according to how it's spelled, ignoring silent letters?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, speech, phonology

Phonetic spelling is when one spells a word according to how it is pronounced (e.g.; knight => nite).
What word would be used to describe the pronunciation of a word based on how it is spelled, ignoring silent letters (e.g.; knife => cuh-nife)?

Comment: I’d call it: “read the way you write”

Comment: Since people don't actually do this, why would there be a word for it?

Comment: "Cuh-nife" is specifically not ignoring silent letters. It's pronouncing silent letters. You should know by now that all letters are silent -- they make no sound. Only speakers make sounds, so all writing is silent. English speakers are burdened with a terrible orthography; if we spoke Finnish we would always pronounce a word according to how it's spelled, since the spelling is based on the sounds. English spelling is based on the sounds and spelling of a dead language (Middle English) and doesn't represent English any more. Knowing how to spell is a weird skill like riding a skateboard.

Comment: Last century, when there were still parking meters, I often would see signs people put on them saying "this won't take my quaters." I am pretty sure it wasn't a typo.

Comment: @Yorik There were still parking meters? There are tons of them where I live in Massachusetts.

Answer (score 0):

It's a form of [**spelling pronunciation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling_pronunciation).